# datagridview to xml file vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, structure

i really needs your kind of help.

i already done writing code from text box + button to create and write into xml file. So now i try to apply the same details but using the datagridview (without textbox).

i'm still new and i really don't know how to apply the cell ,index and everythings about datagridview.

For example my details in TEXTBOX 1 as ID,TEXTBOX 2 as NAME so I transfer to DATAGRIDVIEW  column(0) as ID,column(1) as NAME so everytime user key in the ID and NAME in every row the ID/NAME will goes to the XML file by clicking the button

So i really need your help how to apply this things
here is my code:

```
<i>Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True
    Dim XMLwrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Device.cfg", settings)
    With XMLwrt

        'Write the XML declaration
        .WriteStartDocument()


        'Write the root element
        .WriteStartElement("DEVICES")


        'This will display all elements that user ADD from the button2
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        'For i As Integer = 0 To ioDevice.Length
        Do
            'Start New Device
            .WriteStartElement("DEVICE")


            'Write the attribute element
            .WriteStartAttribute("NAME")
            .WriteString(ioDevice(i).NAME)
            .WriteEndAttribute()


            .WriteStartAttribute("DLL")
            .WriteString(ioDevice(i).Dll)
            .WriteEndAttribute()




            .WriteString(ioDevice(i).ID)


            'The end of Device
            .WriteEndElement()
            i = i + 1


            'the condition where the program should stop looping
        Loop Until (i = ioDevice.Length)


        'Close the XMLTextWritter
        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()

    End With
</i>



  <i>Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    device.ID = Me.TextBox1.Text
</i>



<i>Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) HandlesTextBox1.TextChanged

    device.NAME = Me.TextBox2.Text
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataSource is a DataSet, you can save to XML directly:

```
Dim sFilePath As String = "ENTER A VALID FILEPATH"
NorthwindDataSet.WriteXml(sFilePath)
```

Taken from MSDN: [How to: Save a Dataset as XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233698.aspx)